# How to use buttons to change style of javascript code?

Tags: javascript, button, calendar, styles

A few days before we were asked to create a calender for the month of December and using variables, the current day would be shown witha color. The weekday would be in a different color. However I am struggling with creating button that will change the day after the current day to have a different style as in changing the font or color using CSS. As well as a button that will change the week of the current day to have a different style than the day after the current one. 
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>22plazaa-Unit 3 Day 7</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        * {font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;}
        table, th, td {
            border: 3px solid pink;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table {
            margin:auto;
        }
        td {
            width: 10%;
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 24pt;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h1 {text-align: center}

        #empty {background-color:azure}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Unit 3 Day 7</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th id="sun">Sunday</th>
            <th id="mon">Monday</th>
            <th id="tue">Tuesday</th>
            <th id="wed">Wednesday</th>
            <th id="thu">Thursday</th>
            <th id="fri">Friday</th>
            <th id="sat">Saturday</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="d1">1</td>
            <td id="d2">2</td>
            <td id="d3">3</td>
            <td id="d4">4</td>
            <td id="d5">5</td>
            <td id="d6">6</td>
            <td id="d7">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="d8">8</td>
            <td id="d9">9</td>
            <td id="d10">10</td>
            <td id="d11">11</td>
            <td id="d12">12</td>
            <td id="d13">13</td>
            <td id="d14">14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="d15">15</td>
            <td id="d16">16</td>
            <td id="d17">17</td>
            <td id="d18">18</td>
            <td id="d19">19</td>
            <td id="d20">20</td>
            <td id="d21">21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="d22">22</td>
            <td id="d23">23</td>
            <td id="d24">24</td>
            <td id="d25">25</td>
            <td id="d26">26</td>
            <td id="d27">27</td>
            <td id="d28">28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="d29">29</td>
            <td id="d30">30</td>
            <td id="d31">31</td>
            <td id="end" colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        var today = new Date(); 
        switch (today.getDay()) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("sun").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
                break;
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("mon").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("tue").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("wed").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
                break;
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("thu").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("fri").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
                break;
            case 6:
                document.getElementById("sat").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
                break;
        }
       var date = document.getElementById("d" + today.getDate());
        date.style.color = "white";
        date.style.backgroundColor = "salmon";


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't get you but let me tell you what I understood is, you need a button which will change the date (if today is 8, after click it should go to 9) correct? 
then another scenario is,  how do you know that when to jump to another week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to simply change styles every time you call the click event I made a code snippet showing the run.

I am not sure of what do you mean by different styles try to elaborate.

```js
var nday = document.querySelector('.nday');
var nweek = document.querySelector('.nweek');

nday.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  document.getElementById(Day[today.getDay()]).style.backgroundColor = "white"
  let date = document.getElementById("d" + today.getDate());
  date.style.color = "black";
  date.style.backgroundColor = "white";

  today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1)
  document.getElementById(Day[today.getDay()]).style.backgroundColor = "lightBlue"
  date = document.getElementById("d" + today.getDate());
  date.style.color = "white";
  date.style.backgroundColor = "salmon";

})



nweek.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
document.getElementById(Day[today.getDay()]).style.backgroundColor = "white"
let date = document.getElementById("d" + today.getDate());
date.style.color = "black";
date.style.backgroundColor = "white";


  today.setDate(today.getDate() + 7)
  document.getElementById(Day[today.getDay()]).style.backgroundColor = "lightBlue"
  date = document.getElementById("d" + today.getDate());
  date.style.color = "white";
  date.style.backgroundColor = "salmon";
})

var Day = ["sun", "mon", "tue","wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"]
var today = new Date();
document.getElementById(Day[today.getDay()]).style.backgroundColor = "lightBlue"


var date = document.getElementById("d" + today.getDate());
date.style.color = "white";
date.style.backgroundColor = "salmon";
```

```css
* {font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;}
        table, th, td {
            border: 3px solid pink;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table {
            margin:auto;
        }
        td {
            width: 10%;
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 24pt;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h1 {text-align: center}

        #empty {background-color:azure}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>22plazaa-Unit 3 Day 7</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Unit 3 Day 7</h1>
    <button class = "nday">Next Day</button>
    <button class = "nweek">Next Week</button>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th id="sun">Sunday</th>
            <th id="mon">Monday</th>
            <th id="tue">Tuesday</th>
            <th id="wed">Wednesday</th>
            <th id="thu">Thursday</th>
            <th id="fri">Friday</th>
            <th id="sat">Saturday</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="d1">1</td>
            <td id="d2">2</td>
            <td id="d3">3</td>
            <td id="d4">4</td>
            <td id="d5">5</td>
            <td id="d6">6</td>
            <td id="d7">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="d8">8</td>
            <td id="d9">9</td>
            <td id="d10">10</td>
            <td id="d11">11</td>
            <td id="d12">12</td>
            <td id="d13">13</td>
            <td id="d14">14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="d15">15</td>
            <td id="d16">16</td>
            <td id="d17">17</td>
            <td id="d18">18</td>
            <td id="d19">19</td>
            <td id="d20">20</td>
            <td id="d21">21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="d22">22</td>
            <td id="d23">23</td>
            <td id="d24">24</td>
            <td id="d25">25</td>
            <td id="d26">26</td>
            <td id="d27">27</td>
            <td id="d28">28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="d29">29</td>
            <td id="d30">30</td>
            <td id="d31">31</td>
            <td id="end" colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi this is correct however the button for next week, actually meant the week of the current day instead. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: I am still not sure of what you mean.Can you give an example?

Comment: For example if the current day is December 8, then that week when clicked by the button will all become the same style. The 9th, the 10th and so on until the end of the week which would be the 14th

Comment: You can simply change the nweek.addEventListener function to select the wanted days and change their styles

Comment: May I see the syntax for that I tried to so but the buttons stopped working afterward?